# Request asynchronous processing does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to make my controller (Spring MVC) handle request in parallel. I use @Callable below and it does not work, because next request is handled since first one finished (returns view).

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Callable<String> helloWorld(final Model model) throws InterruptedException {
    return new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return "helloWorld";
        }
    };
}
```

Do I need any special code?

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: When Callable is returned, the second request fires helloWorld. But in reality it waits until first callable return "helloWorld".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) states the following about the `Callable<?>` return type for handler methods

> A Callable can be returned when the application wants to produce
>   the return value asynchronously in a thread managed by Spring MVC.

Spring will take the returned `Callable` instance, pass it to an `ExecutorService` (actually does more processing then than that, but for simplicity) and execute it in a different `Thread` then your initial request. After waiting 5 seconds, it will return the view associated with the view name `"helloWorld"`.

Comment: I can see callable is handled in other thread, but why next request must wait for the first one end to be handled in another thread. I thought whole requests will be handled in parallel...

Comment: How to understand this documentation fragment?

Instead of returning a value, as usual, a controller method can now return a java.util.concurrent.Callable and produce the return value from a separate thread. Meanwhile the main Servlet container thread is released and allowed to process other requests.

Comment: @pawb4r It works fine. Just don't try both requests on the same browser. For example, chrome will realize it is sending the same request and only send one at a time.

Comment: @pawb4r You are reading it perfectly fine. It just so happens that browsers behave this way. Try across browsers or with any Java HTTP client.